# Babel works for german with langscibook, but does not work for spanish

Tags: babel, scrbook, spanish

The documentclass `langscibook` (based on `scrbook`) provides the option `booklanguage` . Default is `english`. I have successfully used `french`, `portuguese`, and `german` in the past.

Internally, the option value is passed to babel.

This sets hyphenation and changes "Contents" to "Table des matières", "Conteúdo", "Inhaltsverzeichnis" and so on.

When I say `booklanguage=spanish` I do get "Índice general" for the table of contents, but compilation stops after that.

```
...
Runaway argument?
! Forbidden control sequence found while scanning use of \language@active@arg~.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.6 \maketitle
              
I suspect you have forgotten a `}', causing me
to read past where you wanted me to stop.
...
```

The following works

```
\documentclass[booklanguage=german]{langscibook}
\author{John Doe}
\title{The test}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\chapter{test}
123
\end{document}
```

When "german" is changed to "spanish", it does not work any longer:

```
\documentclass[booklanguage=spanish]{langscibook}
\author{John Doe}
\title{The test}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\chapter{test}
123
\end{document}
```

The relevant portions of the code in langscibook.cls are

Line 165ff

```
\DeclareStringOption{booklanguage}[english]
    \define@key{langscibook}{booklanguage}{%
        \renewcommand{\lsBookLanguage}{#1}}
```

line 1392

```
    \usepackage[\lsBookLanguage]{babel}
```

When I switch to `{scrbook}` , I can `\usepackage[spanish]{babel}` without problems.

To sum up, `{scrbook}` + babel works with all languages, but `{langscibook}` + babel works with english, german, french, portuguese, and chinese, but not with spanish. I fail to see the reason for this behaviour. Any hints are appreciated.

A minimal working example containing also the `langscibook.cls` file can be found here

https://www.overleaf.com/read/tdrjbmxxhbrp

Answer (score 7, accepted):

spanish redefines the tilde `~` to be an accent. But the class uses it all over the place in the standard meaning of a space, and this clashes. You can tell babel-spanish to leave the tilde alone:

```
\documentclass[booklanguage={spanish,es-notilde}]{langscibook}

\author{John Doe}
\title{The test}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\chapter{test}
123
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This solved the issue. I ran into another issue with ```<``` and ```>```, which are probably also redefined somewhere. I used ```\textrangle``` and ```\textlangle``` to circumvent this.